# Knockout validation with select binding not add ErrorElement.css

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am working with knockout and want user to choose one of item in html select tag.
By default selected empty value

```
<select required>
            <option value="">--Select something</option>
            <option value="True">True</option>
            <option value="False">False</option>
```

And viewModel contain:

```
self.sampleBooleanValue.extend({required : true});
```

I expected that following binding will help

```
<select data-bind="value: sampleBooleanValue" required>

 ....
</select>
```

Validation works, but no css class is added to select tag. 
Can anybody tell why this not work?
P.S. It works with another inputs tags.

Comment: Have you verified that the class isn't added to the select list DOM element? or did you just assume it didn't because the css visual effects weren't showing?

Comment: I verified that it adds only empty class atribute without class name(example: <select .... class ....> )

Comment: Can you post your `ko.validation.init( /* options object */ );` call that you made to configure adding the class name.

Comment: Are you sure you do not have any errors in the markup? Can you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have experienced the same on a more complex model where the error class was not applied, in this case I created a selectedItemNotCaption validator, and that worked where the `required: true` did not (I believe it may have been to do with an error on my mark-up that I had not closed the , but this did work to allow me to investigate further).

Try out the custom validator below, with the [**fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/g18c/qHsS5/6/).

```
model = function () {
var self = this;
self.optionsAvailable = ['one', 'two'];

self.selectedOptionWithRequired = ko.observable().extend({
    required: true
});

self.selectedOption = ko.observable().extend({
    selectedItemNotCaption: true
});

self.submit = function () {
    console.log("checking for errors...");
    self.errors.showAllMessages();
};

self.errors = ko.validation.group(self);
};

ko.validation.configure({
insertMessages: false,
decorateElement: true,
errorElementClass: 'error'
});

ko.validation.rules['selectedItemNotCaption'] = {
validator: function (val) {
    console.log("in validator..." + val);
    return (typeof val != "undefined");
},
message: 'Please select an option'
};

ko.validation.registerExtenders();

ko.applyBindings(new model());
```